# What does the given function mean?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I am having trouble understanding a question.

A function given as :

Let $f (x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y.$
If $f (5)=2$ and $f'(0)=3$ then $f'(5)$ is equal to what?

So the trouble which I am having is.. 
Here it is given $f(5) =2$ which would mean $x+y$ is $5.$ Which can be $2+3, 1+4$ & $0+5.$
 But none of these on being multiplied as $f(x) f(y)$ give $2.$

Or if I think this way:
$f(x)f(y)$ is $2.$ And I get the quadratic equation $x (5-x)^2=2.$ I get an irrational number.

I am sorry if the basic way I thought about it is absolutely wrong. 
I think I am thinking about it in a wrong way. So I need help understanding the given function first then.

Comment: Do you know any basic function that satisfy the property $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$?

Comment: No. That is what I have to figure out in the question. That is why I am having problem figuring it out.  There are four options given with this question and the answer too.

Comment: The fact that you wrote "a function given as" makes me suspect that you may not be understanding the question correctly. The question doesn't actually tell you what the function $f$ *is*. It only gives you partial information about it.

Comment: @Freya Notice that $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$.

Comment: Yes that is right. I did mention that in my question. Also the title asks what the function means not how to figure out an answer to this function.

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495336/a-problem-on-functional-equation-fxy-fxfy

Comment: Thank you Nizar! It is exactly that question. However , while searching for anything alike that didn't come up in my searches. So I asked.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Differentiate the function $g(x) = f(5 + x)$ at $x = 0$ in two different ways.

Edit. As Abstraction points out in a comment, no function $f$ satisfying the hypotheses can actually exist.

Comment: Or, in general: ${d \over dy}f(x+y) = f(x)f'(y) = f'(x+y)$ and for $y=0$ we have $3f(x)=f'(x) \implies f(x)=e^{3x}$ and $f(5)=e^{15}=2$... something's not right here, is it?

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your hint. I did it in one way , another way (?) I haven't done yet. But then in a comment a question as this has been referred to , so I got the help I needed.

Comment: @Abstraction You are correct. You should add that as an answer.